# Retrieving element from a 2D array in column JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

i create a table with a 2D array displaying numbers. Now i want to retrieve element from it. the code below is retrieving it row wise. How can i modify the code below to retrieve it column wise?

```
var newArray;
var buffer ="";
newArray = totalRows.map(function(arrayNode){
        return arrayNode.map(function(node){
               buffer += node.nodeValue.trim();
               cell.innerHTML=buffer;
        });
});
```

Comment: can you show us some more code

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Is this right: if you have `[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]`, you currently get the nodes in the order "123456789", and you instead want them in the order "147258369"?